# .NET Core 3.1 - remove Server header

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers

I try to remove the Server header  sent by my app

```
.UseKestrel((builderContext, options) => options.AddServerHeader = false)
```

and this is the config I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576" maxQueryString="2048" maxUrl="4096" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

yet the Server header appear on each request

[image]

is there something I am missing ?

thanks

Comment: Hmm... It would seem to me that you are debugging using IIS and not kestrel - to verify, perhaps create a build and then execute the .dll using the `dotnet-cli`

Comment: Alternatively - google how to remove the IIS server header from your IIS instance :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is not your application adding the header, but IIS:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="Server" />
...
...
<system.webServer/>
```

Perhaps try the above in your web config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URLScan tool.

Open the URLScan.ini file typically located in the %WINDIR%\System32\Inetsrv\URLscan folder. After opening it, search for the key RemoveServerHeader . By default it is set to 0, but to remove the Server header, change the value to 1.

Official documentation：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-overview